# jQuery: selector question (parent)

Tags: jquery, selector

i'm having this markup:

```
<ul class=container>

    <li rec=1>
        <div>
           <div>
               <div>i'm here</div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

now i'm at the div element ("i'm here"), how can i get reference to the li?
i tried `div.parent("li");` but didntwork ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
closest("li")
```

rather than parent http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest  Parent only gets the direct parent.

Comment: If the hierarchy levels are known, but you don't know what type of tag the great-grandparent (the li in this case) will be, then you can do this: $("div").contains("i'm here").parent().parent().parent();

Answer (score 1):

[`parent`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent) is used to get the unique **direct antecesor** of an element, which in your case is a `div`.

You should use [`parents`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parents) or [`closest`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest):

```
div.parents("li");
```